# Validating a CPR number

Tags: code-golf, number, date

## Validating a CPR number

A Danish CPR number (*Person Identification Number*) is date of birth followed by 4 digits (the last one being a control digit): DDMMYY-XXXX

The final digit validates the CPR number using Modulo 11 by satisfying the following equation:

[image: mod11]

where the [image] are the ten digits of the complete ID number, and the coefficients (4, 3, 2, 7, …) are all nonzero in the finite field of order 11.

## Input

A CPR number formatted like this DDMMYY-XXXX where YY indicates a year within the last 100 years (between 1917 and 2016).

## Output

Indication whether CPR number is valid (1 or true) or invalid (0 or false)

## Examples

```
  290215-2353 --> false
  140585-2981 --> true
  311217-6852 --> true
  121200-0004 --> false
  140322-5166 --> false
  111111-1118 --> true
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) - fewest bytes win!

## Date validation

All years refer to a period within the last 100 years. A valid date is a date that exists within it's calendar year.

**290215** is not a valid date because 29/2 wasn't a date in 2015.

**301216** is a valid date because 30/12 is a date in 2016.

Comment: Can I receive the input as an array of the ten digits?

Comment: Could you show how the first one evaluates to be false?

Comment: Traditionally a CPR number includes the hyphen so I'm gonna say no - it's a string :)

Comment: @LeakyNun: Look at the date :)

Comment: What kind of date validation needs to be done?  Do we have to check for leap years?  Calendar changes?  Check if the birthday is more recent than today?

Comment: @NathanMerrill All years (YY) will refer to dates within the last 100 years (from 1917 to 2016) and never newer than today. Thus date validation (including checking for leap years) will be neccesary for this 100-year period of time

Comment: I've updated the post again. @NathanMerrill does this answer your question?

Comment: @Daniel  within the last 100 years includes certain dates in 1916 (like 12/31/2015).  Are those valid?

Comment: @NathanMerrill 311215 refers the 31'st of december 2015 - remember you don't have all the 4 year digits (YYYY) only the last two (YY) and they always represent the latest year that ends with these two digits

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant `12/31/1915`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42798/discussion-between-daniel-and-nathan-merrill).

Comment: Actually, as of 1 Oct '07, the last digit isn't a control digit anymore, so no validation is possible. You should update the text, and change the test cases from the last ten years.

Comment: @Adám I am aware of this change, but I decided it shouldn't stand in the way of a codegolf challenge :)

Comment: I'm guessing that the symbol `0` represents the digit with decimal value `10`, but that could be clearer.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Actually, no: "If the division remainder [is] 1, the designated serial number (digits 7-9) [is] not used, because the check digit thus would be two-digit (10), which is not possible."  [(source)](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fda.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCPR-nummer%23Kontrolciffer_.28det_gamle_CPR-nummer.29&edit-text=&act=url) (sorry for google translate, but it seems to be correct if I use my knowledge of German to read the danish text)

Answer (score 2):

## Python (2), <s>167</s> <s>156</s> <s>155</s> <s>142</s> 141 bytes

```python
from time import*
def f(s):
 try:return 1>sum(int(i)*(ord(j)-48)for i,j in zip("43276504321",s))%11;strptime(s[:6],"%d%m%y")
 except:return 0
```

tried to do the date validation without the library, but it's 168 bytes:

```python
lambda s:sum(int(i)*(ord(j)-48)for i,j in zip("43276504321",s))%11==0 and int(s[0:2])<([0,32,(29,30)[int(s[4:6])%4==0],32]+[31,32]*2+[32,31]*2+[32]+[0]*99)[int(s[2:4])]
```

*-12 bytes thanks to @GáborFekete*

*-14 bytes thanks to @RootTwo*

Comment: You can golf some bytes by using `s[:6]` instead of `s.split("-")[0]` and also by removing the space before the `for`.

Comment: thank you, now i just gotta save 1 byte somewhere to beat the php solution despite the horrendous date validation in Python.

Comment: Move the last line after the line starting with `try` using a semicolon.

Comment: Does that save characters? (you lose a " " but add a ";"). However, I had a similar idea before I read your comment (see above)

Comment: Great answer! When golfing, it is a good idea to keep your old byte counts by surrounding them with `<s>` and `<\s>` in the markdown editor, which adds a strikethrough.

Comment: Thank you, i was wondering how to do that and the markdown standard `~~` didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `</s>`, which you noticed anyway.

Comment: It saved you a newline!

Comment: you are correct (missed that -.-), so my 'one return instead of two' shenanigans did exactly nothing to the bytecount

Comment: Can save 12 bytes by using `time.strptime()` instead of `datetime.datetime.strptime()`.

Comment: @RootTwo Thank you! Have have looked for some shorter time function but didn't find this one.

Comment: You can save another byte using `r=1>sum` instead of `r=0==sum`.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>145</s> <s>113</s> <s>112</s> 103 + 8 (`-nrdate` flags) = 111 bytes

Returns a date object (truthy) if it's a valid CPR, `false` if it fails the modulo test, and `nil` (falsy) if it fails the date test. Input is STDIN.

*-33 bytes from @Jordan*

```
s=0
$_.size.times{|i|s+=12340567234/10**i%10*$_[i].to_i}
p s%11<1&&Date.strptime($_,"%d%m%y")rescue p p
```

Version that returns literal `true` on valid CPR for +1 byte:

```
s=0
$_.size.times{|i|s+=12340567234/10**i%10*$_[i].to_i}
p Date.strptime($_,"%d%m%y")&&s%11<1 rescue p p
```

Version that returns an error on invalid date instead of `nil`, for -10 bytes but probably invalid:

```
s=0
$_.size.times{|i|s+=12340567234/10**i%10*$_[i].to_i}
p Date.strptime($_,"%d%m%y")&&s%11<1
```

Comment: Might I suggest `Date.strptime("%d%m%y", $_)`?

Comment: @Jordan I was about to say that it would cause errors for "121118" giving the year as 2018, but then I remembered that the leap years are all the same (except for 1900 which is out of the year scope anyways). Also, the arguments are in the reverse order so I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 130 bytes

```
DateObject[a={10#5+#6+4,10#3+#4,10#+#2}][[1]]==a&&11∣Tr[{4,3,2,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}{##}]&@@IntegerDigits@FromDigits[#~StringDrop~{7}]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a string as input and returns `True` or `False` as output. The Unicode character is U+2223 DIVIDES, representing `\[Divides]`.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby + GNU date, <del>112</del> <del>111</del> 103 bytes

-8 bytes from Kevin Lau.

```
->n{s=0
n.size.times{|i|s+=12340567234/10**i%10*n[i].to_i}
n=~/#{"(..)"*3}/
s%11<1&&`date -d#$3#$2#$1`>""}
```

Note that this prints e.g. "`date: invalid date ‘150229’`" to stderr if the date portion is invalid, but it still returns `true` or `false` (it doesn't raise an exception). If that's a disqualifier, though, I can add `⎵2>/dev/null` for a 12-byte penalty.

### Ungolfed

```
v = ->(cpr) {
  sum = 0

  cpr.size.times do |idx|
    sum += 12340567234 / 10**idx % 10 * cpr[idx].to_i
  end

  cpr =~ /#{"(..)" * 3}/
  sum % 11 < 1 && `date -d#$3#$2#$1` > ""
}
```

Comment: Errors are allowed? If so that cuts a lot of bytes off of my own Ruby solution :o

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny I think that's up to Daniel, hence the note.

Comment: FWIW this still returns `true` or `false`, even when the date is invalid. It doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: Hmm, that's true. I'm tempted to use your `zip` trick with the block but it feels like cheating and I'd probably outpace yours by using it...

Comment: You would indeed. A quandary!

Comment: It's OK, I managed to tie you with an alternate solution (turns out the zip trick wasn't enough bytes saved). And now you can use my technique and make yours even shorter!